# angular2: passing property between components

Tags: angular, typescript

I am practising angular2 (using ionic framework) and I am having difficulties with passing data between components.

This is `app.component.ts`:

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar>
        <button ion-button icon-only menuToggle>
          <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
        </button>
        <ion-title>MyApp</ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>

    <user-menu></user-menu>
    <ion-content padding>
      <h1>Active User: {{ activeUser }}</h1>
    </ion-content>
  `
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage = TablePage;

  constructor(platform: Platform) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
      Splashscreen.hide();
    });
  }
}
```

This is `user-menu.component.ts`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'user-menu',
  template: `
    <ion-menu [content]="userMenu">
      <ion-content>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-list>
            <ion-list-header>
              Users
            </ion-list-header>
            <ion-item *ngFor="let user of users;" menuClose [class.selected]="user === activeUser" (tap)="onSelect(user)">
              {{ user.name }}
            </ion-item>
          </ion-list>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-menu>

    <ion-nav #userMenu [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>
  `,
  styles: [`
    .selected {
      background-color: #CFD8DC !important;
      color: white;
    }
  `],
  providers: [UserService]
})
export class UserMenuComponent {
  users: User[];
  activeUser: User;

  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

  getUsers(): void {
    this.userService.getUsers().then(users => this.users = users);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getUsers();
  }

  onSelect(user: User): void {
    this.activeUser = user;
  }
}
```

How can I get`activeUser` in the main component? In the next step I would like to display relevant data according to this user and maybe even pass it to a third component.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) The template reference migh work for you

```
<user-menu #menu></user-menu>

{{ menu.activeUser }}
```

See also

- [Parent interacts with child via local variable](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-child-local-var)

2) Another way is having @Output event in `UserMenuComponent`

```
export class UserMenuComponent {
  @Output() onSelected = new EventEmitter();

  onSelect(user: User): void {
    this.activeUser = user;
    this.onSelected.emit(user);
  }
```

and use it in parent template

```
<user-menu (onSelected)="activeUser = $event"></user-menu>
```

See also

- [Parent listens for child event](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#child-to-parent)

Comment: Wahh! What just happened? Can you explain please?

Comment: You just get reference to `UserMenuComponent` instance and can have access to its properties

Comment: Thanks! When it is better to use the template reference method and when the @Output event method?

Comment: Your use case is better suited for the @Output event method  (having data flow from child to parent). Using the template reference is for the more complicated case where you may want to use functionality from the UserMenu (i.e. call methods on it) from the parent MyApp

Comment: @Snorkpete Thank you.